# Will cold weather hurt tomato yields this summer?

Tags: tomatoes, cold-weather, climate

I planted 6" tall cherry tomato starts that I'd been nurturing under lights indoors for a few weeks. Of course, immediately after I put them out, an absurd cold snap in Seattle (see below) saw a week of temperatures in the mid 40s during the day, high 30s at night. I did not provide protection.

The tomatoes are still alive but looking sad. Will they bounce back, or should I just rip them out and put new ones in once temperatures return to normal? There was no frost.

[image]

Comment: Please post a photo so we know how sad they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While things might be *better* if you had been able to offer them some protection, in general if they survive, they are already at least a week ahead on dealing with transplant shock, *etcetera*; *.vs.* new transplants and will bounce back once the weather warms to temperatures that suit tomatoes better.